# identifying possible overfitting in SVM

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, svm, libsvm

SVM can avoid overfitting with the right choice of parameters. How to know if the trained svm is overfitted? Is there a way to identify that?How to avoid that? Can testing with unseen data help?

Comment: I am not sure if there is a canonical way to do that, but probably the easier way to do it is by comparing results between your testing dataset and your validation dataset. A huge difference between results might indicate a generalization problem.

Answer (score 0):

The libSVM metatraining does exactly that for you. If you have data unseen to the (meta)training you could do the prediction for this test data and compare its performance to the performance for the training data. A small gap is ok while a big gap is an indicator for overfitting or too little training data.